# Pattern Attribute in Input Type E-Mail Breaks Angular Partial

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

I have an input like so in an angular partial

```
<input type='email' pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" />
```

However the pattern seems to be breaking the partial. When I remove it, the view can be displayed no problem. But leaving it in causes a parse error when a request is made for the partial.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `ng-pattern` and `^` anchor at the beginning of regex.

Comment: So like pattern="^[a-z0-9._% etc..." ?

Comment: `ng-pattern="/^[\w.%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i"`

Comment: Care to comment on the down vote?

Comment: Please share the code you have, otherwise, no one can help you as we just do not know where the issue is. The regex below or my suggestion must work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<ng-pattern>` instead of pattern

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/"
```

Working [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/e1lWUl52Dk7I7NcLYUrZ?p=preview) here

Comment: Still seem to be breaking it for some reason!

Comment: Means demo is breaking or your code still breaking?